# scientific form with padding and exponent

Tags: output-formatting

I would like to print 1 as 1.00x10^0 by using ScientificForm/PaddedForm.
I've tried with

```
ScientificForm[{N@Sqrt[2]*1*^2, N@\[Pi], 1}, 3, NumberFormat -> (Row@{PaddedForm[#1, {2, 2}], "\[Times]", 
  Superscript["10", ToString[#3]]} &)]
```

but I've missed both the exponent (the zero) and the right
padding zeros.

Can someone help me?
Thanks,
Fabio

Comment: Try this `PaddedForm[ {N@Sqrt[2]*1*^2, N@\[Pi], 1.0}, {3, 2},
 ExponentFunction -> (1 Quotient[#, 1] &), 
 NumberFormat -> (Row@{#1, "\[Times]", 
      Superscript["10", ToString[#3]]} &)
 ]`

Answer (score 3):

N.J.Evans answer in comments:

```
PaddedForm[{N@Sqrt[2]*1*^2, N@π, 1.0}, {3, 2}, 
 ExponentFunction -> (1 Quotient[#, 1] &), 
 NumberFormat -> (Row@{#1, "×", 
      Superscript["10", ToString[#3]]} &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much, tricky though simple!